# String To Double Converter with IValueConverter C#

Tags: c#, string, double, ivalueconverter, converters

I have a View in which I should be able to input doubles. The thing is, I can only input whole numbers such as "100" but not "100.4". All my background calculations run on doubles though. 
I'm now trying to bypass the problem by implementing a StringToDoubleConverter but my C# knowledge is still very limited.

I've implemented this into my `UserControl.Resources` tag

```
<local:StringToDoubleConverter x:Key="StringToDouble"/>
```

and created a new class StringToDoubleConverter:

```
class StringToDoubleConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            string stringNumber = value as string;
            double.TryParse(stringNumber, out double val);
            return val;
        }
    }
```

Finally I've implemented the converter into my binding:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}, Path=DelayModel.DelayTime, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Converter={StaticResource StringToDouble}}"/>
```

My `DelayTime` in my `DelayModel` looks like this:

```
private double _delayTime;

public double DelayTime
{
    get
    {
        return _delayTime;
    }
    set
    {
        if (value != _delayTime)
        {
            _delayTime = value; NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

I know my converter is somehow wrong. I'm struggling to get the right code to convert the string I want to input in my View to doubles.

For example: I want to input "0.7" into my View and `DelayTime` should actually get "0.7" and not just the "7". Is TryParse oder double.Parse(value) correct?

Comment: What culture is your PC set to?  Does it use a period for decimal point?

Comment: I'm german. I want to use "." or "," for decimal points. Either one is fine. But right now I can't enter either of them. What I *can* do is: type: "1" then use the left arrow key and write a ".", the program will automatically put a 0 in front. It now shows "0.1" and it works. But thats not very intuitive...

Comment: your problem is using UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged. It update the source after pressing each key. If you put the point character, it update the source with string value "0." what give you back "0" without point. You can change UpdateSourceTrigger to Default and update Source manually when you press Enter.

Comment: One should work and the other fail.  Not both fail.  If you want bot the work then us TryParse and when one fails then use different culture and try second one.  Or change period/comma to other one using string method.

Comment: You can try this `decimal.TryParse(stringNumber, NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture out decimal val)`. `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` will take care of the decimal character, whatever it is.

Comment: @StefanW. Your answer helped me. Now the value is not instantly changed but whatever... It works :D thanks!

Comment: @StefanW. Is there a way to get Enter to work? If I delete the UpdateSourceTrigger it should fallback to the Default. But Enter doesn't work. Default behaves like LostFocus. I've tried all triggers (Default, Explicit, LostFocus). Is there a way to register 'Enter'-input?

Comment: @ikerbera I've tried your method, but stringNumber will always be null. Is anything missing? I think the real problem is actually PropertyChanged

Comment: `stringNumber` is the value that the converter gets. In your code you initialize it like this `string stringNumber = value as string;`. So, as long as `value` is not null it should be working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need StringToDoubleConverter.

The problem is using UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged. It update the source after pressing each key. If you put the point character, it update the source with string value "0." what give you back "0" without point. You can change UpdateSourceTrigger to Default and update Source manually when you press Enter with KeyDown event

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}, Path=DelayModel.DelayTime}" KeyDown="TextBox_KeyDown"/>
```

and code behind

```
private void TextBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.Key == Key.Enter)
            (sender as TextBox).GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty).UpdateSource();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Stefan! The Key.Enter-Method was really helpful.